# Q: How would I split Vue Router (v4) into muliple files

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I could use some help with Vue Router. I'm using Vue 3 and have been reading though the router [documentation](https://next.router.vuejs.org/) and searching for solutions, but I've not yet found an answer to my question.

I'm fairly new to Vue itself, and my router file is beginning to get quite large. I've tried several different methods that I've found online to split my router file, but none seem to work (they are for previous version of Vue). Are you aware of any resources that I can read through, or am I just missing something?

I've tried creating a router file for admin routes, importing and pushing into the router using router.push() but when I load the application, the route is not found.

Example:

/router/index.js

```
import { createRouter, createWebHistory } from 'vue-router'
import Authentication from '@/views/Public/Authentication.vue'
import NotFound from '@/views/Public/NotFound.vue'
import NetworkError from '@/views/Public/NetworkError.vue'

import adminRoutes from '@/modules/admin/router'

const routes = [
  {
    path: '/',
    redirect: '/admin'
  },
  {
    path: '/auth',
    name: 'Auth',
    component: Authentication
  },
  {
    path: '/:catchAll(.*)',
    name: 'NotFound',
    component: NotFound
  },
  {
    path: '/404/:resource',
    name: '404resource',
    component: NotFound,
    props: true
  },
  {
    path: '/network-error',
    name: 'NetworkError',
    component: NetworkError
  }
]

router.push(adminRoutes);

const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHistory(process.env.BASE_URL),
  routes
})
```

/modules/admin/router/index.js

```
import Admin from '@/views/Admin/Admin.vue'
import Dashboard from '@/views/Admin/Dashboard.vue'
import Settings from '@/views/Admin/Settings.vue'

export default [
  {
    path: '/admin',
    name: 'Admin',
    component: Admin,
    children: [
        {
          path: 'Dashboard',
          component: Dashboard
        },
        {
          path: 'settings',
          component: Settings
        }
      ]
  },
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Welp. I answered my own question. I think I've been staring at this problem for so long, my eyes were tired. Here is what worked for me, but def open to feedback if there are better ways:

```
import { createRouter, createWebHistory } from 'vue-router'
import Authentication from '@/views/Public/Authentication.vue'
import NotFound from '@/views/Public/NotFound.vue'
import NetworkError from '@/views/Public/NetworkError.vue'

import adminRoutes from '@/modules/admin/router'

const routes = [
  ...adminRoutes,
  {
    path: '/',
    redirect: '/admin'
  },
  {
    path: '/auth',
    name: 'Auth',
    component: Authentication
  },
  {
    path: '/:catchAll(.*)',
    name: 'NotFound',
    component: NotFound
  },
  {
    path: '/404/:resource',
    name: '404resource',
    component: NotFound,
    props: true
  },
  {
    path: '/network-error',
    name: 'NetworkError',
    component: NetworkError
  }
]

router.push(adminRoutes);

const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHistory(process.env.BASE_URL),
  routes
})
```

Comment: `routes.push(adminRoutes)` and `...adminRoutes` a redundant bro.